# How to create array of pairs of strings?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C and I have been trying to create and print an array of pairs of strings for a while now but keep getting errors. Here's what I want the array to look like:

```
[[str1, str2], [str3, str4], ...]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
...
char str1[51], str2[51];
char *pairs[amount][2][51];
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
    // assign str at ith index of pairs and 0th/1st index within pair
    *pairs[i][0] = str1;
    *pairs[i][1] = str2;
}
// print pairs in backwards order
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    printf("%s %s", *pairs[i][1], *pairs[i][0]);
}
```

Input:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Output:

```
6 5
6 5
6 5
```

My interpretation of this is to declare a char array of pointers to pairs of strings, each string containing upwards of 50 chars, then assign strings to each pair and print them backwards. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, but what? It seems like only the last pair is being accessed.

I know I can just print the strings backwards as they're being inputted, but I'm trying to understand arrays and declarations better.

Comment: Note that `*pairs[i][0]` is exactly the same as `pairs[i][0][0]`. Which makes no sense even if the pointers are initialized. Also note that the assignment will make *all* pointers exactly the same, you need to allocate memory dynamically and copy the strings (while not part of C, almost all systems have a `strdup` function that can be used). Remember to `free` the memory once you're done with it. Or instead of dynamic allocation, an array which you can `strcpy` the strings into?

Comment: @SupportUkraine is there a way to do it using just normal arrays instead of a struct?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have no idea how memory allocation works yet so I'll go learn that later, but why couldn't you directly assign strings into the array instead of using `strcpy`?

Comment: The assignment `pairs[i][0] = str1` is the same as `pairs[i][0] = &str1[0]`. With the assignment you copy *the pointer* to the first element of `str1`. You do not copy the whole string. That means *all* `pairs[i][0]` (for all `i`) elements will have the exact same pointer.

Comment: To help you understand pointers better I suggest you get a pencil and some paper. On the paper draw three boxes: One that you label `str1`, one that you label `pairs[0][0]` and one that you label `pairs[1][0]`. From each of the two `pairs` boxes, draw an arrow to the `str1` box. That's basically how pointers works: They *point* somewhere else. And this drawing should make it quite clear that both `pairs` are pointing to the exact same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I kind of get pointers now, thanks. Also probably should've known that arrays can't be assigned to arrays beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem is:

```
*pairs[i][0] = str1;
```

This copies the reference (and not the value) of `str1` to `pairs[i][0]`.
If you want to copy the value, You should use `strcpy()` function in `string.h` header file.
Another solution is the following example:

### An example without struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char list_of_pairs[3][2][51];
    printf("Enter your pairs:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        scanf(" %s %s", list_of_pairs[i][0], list_of_pairs[i][1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("pair -> first: %s second: %s\n", list_of_pairs[i][0], list_of_pairs[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array pointers make sense if you want to dynamically allocate the memory

```
#define MAXLENGTH 51

char (*addPair(size_t size, char (*array)[2][MAXLENGTH], const char *s1, const char *s2))[2][MAXLENGTH]
{
    array = realloc(array, ++size * sizeof(*array));

    if(array)
    {
        strncpy(array[size -1][0], s1, sizeof(array[0][0]));
        strncpy(array[size -1][1], s2, sizeof(array[0][0]));
        array[size -1][0][MAXLENGTH - 1] = 0;
        array[size -1][1][MAXLENGTH - 1] = 0;
    }
    return array;
}
```